# Using Ehrenfest relation in the case of a Harmonic oscillator.

Tags: physics, quantum-mechanics

I have the Ehrenfest relation $\frac{d}{dt}\langle\mathbf{p}\rangle=-\langle\nabla V(\mathbf{r})\rangle$. I need to write this in the case of the harmonic oscillator potential $V(\mathbf{r})=\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2\mathbf{r}^2$. From this, how would I solve this using a coupled system of differential equations for $\langle\mathbf{r}\rangle$ and $\langle\mathbf{p}\rangle$ as functions of time?

I tried using the original Ehrenfest relation $\frac{d}{dt}\langle\mathbf{r}\rangle= \frac{1}{m}\langle\mathbf{p}\rangle$ but got nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

The two equations you are looking for are simply:
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt}\langle\mathbf{p}\rangle = -\langle \nabla V(\mathbf r)\rangle = -\langle \nabla \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2 r^2\rangle = \frac{-1}{2}m\omega^2 \langle \nabla (x^2+y^2+z^2)\rangle = -m\omega^2\langle \mathbf{r} \rangle
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt}\langle\mathbf{r}\rangle= \frac{1}{m}\langle\mathbf{p}\rangle
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you, would you know the reasoning behind why this method of working out expectation values wouldn't work if the potential was of the form $V(\mathbf{r})=\frac{\alpha}{|\mathbf{r}|}$?

Comment: If we have a potential of the form $V(\mathbf{r}) = \frac{\alpha}{|\mathbf{r}|}$, it would only depend  on the distance to the origin so it would be the potential of a central force (in this case an inverse $1/r^2$ force). Thus, $\frac{d}{dt}\langle \mathbf{p} \rangle = \alpha \langle \frac{1}{r^2}\hat{\mathbf{r}} \rangle$.